# How to find the main class in this Kotlin project. I have tried everything I can think of and I can't find the main class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

for the past couple of days I have been trying to get specific program running in Android studio. One of the biggest problems with trying to get this program running is that I cannot find what the main class for the project is. I have tried everything I can possibly think of including reading several articles from android themselves about what the main class is and where it should be. I am beyond confused as to why I have not been able to find the main class even though I have looked everywhere. how exactly does one find the main class in a Kotlin project? I am also having difficulties specifying the JDK for some reason it is not appearing as an option to set it in the settings. I am running Android studio 3.4.2 if that matters in any way. I will like the project below:

https://github.com/softbankrobotics-labs/pepper-gamepad

Thanks so much for the help!

I have tried to find the main class for a Kotlin project so I can run it on my Pepper robot, but I have been unable to find it. I also cannot specify the JDK in the settings of Android Studio 3.4.2.

Comment: https://github.com/softbankrobotics-labs/pepper-gamepad/blob/master/pepper-gamepad-root/sample-app/src/main/java/com/softbankrobotics/peppergamepadsample/MainActivity.kt < That's the main activity, if that's what you mean

Comment: Also, AS 3.4.2 is pretty old, I'd upgrade to the latest

Comment: Whenever I try to run the program, I have to fill out a box that says Main class:____________. I have no idea what to put here, and I have tried a lot of different things but none of them have worked.

Comment: There is no Main class in an Android project. Doesn't matter if you're using Java or Kotlin.

Comment: ok, then why is it asking for it, and giving me an error that says Class not found whenever I try to run the program? I'm just trying to understand what is happening and why.

Comment: What means are you using to try to run the program?

Comment: I am trying to run the program in Android studio because that is the only way to connect to the robot that I am trying to run the program on.

Comment: I guess Gradle was unable to build it correctly

Comment: I see. Well thanks for the help. I will see if I can tweak my approach to running it.

Answer (score 1):

Android projects don't have a `main` function, if that's what you mean - there isn't really a *main class* either, you control what your app launches into through [intent filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters). The system is responsible for actually running things, and it ends up calling callback functions which are the entrypoint to your code - things like `onCreate` in an `Activity`, `onReceive` in a `BroadcastReceiver` etc.

In the app's manifest file (`AndroidManifest.xml`) you set one of your `Activities` to use a filter with the `action.MAIN` and `category.LAUNCHER` attributes, that's the Activity that opens when you start the app normally (e.g. by tapping the app icon in the launcher). That's the way you specify a *"main"* Activity, the main entry point to your app. [The sample app in the project you linked does this](https://github.com/softbankrobotics-labs/pepper-gamepad/blob/master/pepper-gamepad-root/sample-app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml).

If you've cloned that project and opened it, I'm guessing that for some reason you don't have a *run configuration* that defines it as an Android app. Here's the default one from the docs:

[image: The default Run Configuration for an Android project]

It doesn't need to ask for a *"main class"* because like we've covered, Android apps don't have them! So make sure you're not trying to run this as a standalone Kotlin project (which has nothing to do with the Android framework). You can read more about Run Configurations [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig)

Comment: thank you so much I will give this a try as soon as I am able to! You just saved me a lot of headaches. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: I cloned the repository and for some reason the module is not specified like it is in your photo. How do I specify the correct module? I am fairly new to android studio.

Comment: @Sanders You need to make sure your run config is an *Android App* one (when you create a new one there are default templates) and then you should be able to pick the *sample app* module. If it's not showing up, run a Gradle sync (*Ctrl+Shift+A* and start typing if you ever want to do a thing in Android Studio!) and try again. Make sure you have the whole project too - everything inside *pepper-gamepad-root*, that's the actual project. *sample-app* and *pepper-gamepad* are *modules* in that project: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects

Comment: I have tried to run a gradle sync using Ctrl+Shift+A and nothing happened. I also do not see the gradle sync icon anywhere on the top bar of android studio. Is there a specific way I am supposed to run a gradle sync?

Comment: @Sanders you have to type what you're looking for after Ctrl+Shift+A, it's like a search for commands and options. The sync icon you can see here (https://developer.android.com/studio/intro#the_user_interface) below the end of the window title, to the left of the folder icon - like a circle with rotating arrows around it. Older versions use an elephant with an arrow. Honestly I can't help you troubleshoot Gradle or an AS installation, if it doesn't seem to recognise your project as a project, all I can suggest is starting over with `Import Project` and point it at `pepper-gamepad-root`, sorry!

Comment: You are fine, no need to apologize! You have helped a lot, I am far closer to getting this working than I was earlier. Thank you so much and have a great rest of your week.